# How to actually check for null to comply with Sound null-safety in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the recommended way to check for null with the new "sound null-safety" feature of Dart , specially for the compiler to stop complaining, this doesn't work:

[image]

I'm obviously checking that value.data isn't null before accessing it.

Comment: @Dude That might assign `null` to `profile.profilePic` which might not be allowed or desired, while the code in the screen shot ignores the case where `value.data == null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only local variables will get promoted.

so if you say

```
final temp = value.data;

if(temp != null) {
   profile.profilePic = temp.url;
}
```

it should work.

Comment: yikes, this sound null-safety thing is cool but this is a lot of code added if we want to play by the rules.

Comment: In general it’s not that bad. I think this is the worse case.

Answer (score -1):

define

```
yourVariable? aNullableInt = null;
```

Comment: can you be more specific?